# Delete function for multi data

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I create a collection like above .Can i able to write query to delete a specific addons from this collection? 
In here my partition key is id .

```
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Subcategory": [{
    "Product": [{
      "MethodOfPreparation": [{ }],
      "Addons": [{ }]
    }]
  }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point out a point firstly,i presume you are talking about Document,not Collection.

Using sql to delete documents is not possible so far. You need to fetch the documents using SELECT query and then delete the documents individually using DELETE SDK.

If you want to remove partial of document like your description in your question,you need to select the document first to get rid of the parts you want to remove,then [replace the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.replacedocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet).Please see this newly [blog](https://thedavidmasters.com/2019/01/01/cosmosdb-updating-a-document-partially/).